# linux mint keyboard shortcut can't start

Tags: shortcut, linux-mint

I just installed linux mint mate 16, I can config shortcut via "system -> preference -> keyboard shortcut", but after a while, I can't start "system -> preference -> keyboard shortcut", it shows "starting ..." for a while, then it disappear, so I can't config shortcut any more.
I don't know why, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It seems mint mate 17 RC fixed this issue, but mint mate 17 final release introduce this issue again, unbelievable.

I found a temp solution from following link:
http://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/1kss09/keyboard_shortcuts_command/

**steps to fix:**

- first install: `sudo apt-get install dconf-cli`
- then reset key binding: `dconf reset -f /org/mate/desktop/keybindings/`
- then you can start keyboard shortcuts, but all self-add shortcuts are gone, need to define again, and you must define everything at 1 time without close the window, because once you close the window, you can't open it again without reset the keys that you have add.